# Localization and binding don't work together

Tags: windows-phone-7, globalization

I'm developing my first app and I'm trying to make it multilanguage.
Using [AppHub example](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/87002/522440.aspx) and some other link I created my resource files, fixed binding strings on my components and set a settings page.
First problem I had was that menu items and appbar buttons couldn't use localization strings (project complained when launched) so I have:

- TextBlocks and other components binded with localized strings
- Appbar buttons and items localized manually with a procedure loading localized strings

Now that I have my settings page, one item user can change is language.
Well, correct CultureInfo is selected according to user selection and then I use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Settings.Language;
```

When I press back button and return to main page, appbar items are localized correctly, while everything else is not.
The only workaround (that I really don't like, it's just to understand) is this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Settings.Language;
    InitializeComponent();
    // Everything else I need here
}
```

so I have to set language before components are created to make it work.
What's wrong? Which is the correct way to make a page refresh after changing language using binded strings?
I did not put a lot of code because I used basically the one provided in the link, but if you need more info I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to automatically update my application components reacting to language change.
A good tutorial can be found [here](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.it/2012/03/instant-language-update-in-windows.html); briefly you must find a way to notify your app that localized resource is changed.

```
  public class LocalizedStrings : ViewModelBase
  {
      private static AppResources localizedresources = new AppResources();

      public AppResources LocalizedResources
      {
          get { return localizedresources; }
      }

      public void UpdateLanguage()
      {
          localizedresources = new AppResources();
          RaisePropertyChanged(() => LocalizedResources);
      }

      public static LocalizedStrings LocalizedStringsResource
      {
          get
          {
              return Application.Current.Resources["LocalizedStrings"]
                     as LocalizedStrings;
          }
      }
  }
```

With this when user change language, you should simply run

```
LocalizedStrings.LocalizedStringsResource.UpdateLanguage();
```

and the job is done.

Comment: This only works for xaml though. I wonder if you have a generic way to update resources defined in code-behind?